# knockout.js - component registration

Tags: knockout.js

I'm having an issue with component registration.
I'm using ko.components.register providing viewmodel and template (and it works for other components) but when I check if one of my components isRegistered I got 'false' and an error printed out in console 'Uncaught Error: Unknown component'. 
Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your code to your question?

Comment: is the browser loading it?

Comment: I missed some imports on the way, thanks!